# ¿Concatenar varios registros en una cadena para mostrarlo en uno solo? LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

tengo una tabla llamada Technologys y cada Technology puede tener una o mas resolutions.
Lo que quiero hacer es que se muestren todas las resoluciones que tiene una tecnologia en un mismo campo.

Ejemplo

```
Tabla de tecnologias
Nombre   Descripcion   Resoluciones
1        prueba        140,33,32
```

Necesito hacerlo con linq y me han dicho que la clave esta en un String Join o en un Agregate usando dos querys pero no puedo conseguirlo.

Este es mi codigo:

```
  var Technology1 = (from  tTechnology in Context.Technology

                                                 join tUsers in Context.Users on tTechnology.EnableBy equals tUsers.UserId into collection
                                                 from subCase in collection.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                 join tUsers2 in Context.Users on tTechnology.LastChangeBy equals tUsers2.UserId into collection2
                                                 from subCase2 in collection2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                 join tUsers3 in Context.Users on tTechnology.DisableBy equals tUsers3.UserId into collection3
                                                 from subCase3 in collection3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                 join tResolution in Context.Resolution on tTechnology.TechnologyId equals tResolution.TechnologyId 
                                                 into collection4
                                                 from subCase4 in collection4.DefaultIfEmpty()                  
                                                 where tTechnology.DisableDate == null



                             //orderby 

            select new
            {
                tTechnologyTechnologyId = tTechnology.TechnologyId,
                tTechnologyName = tTechnology.Name,
                tTechnologyDescription = tTechnology.Description,
                tCityName = tTechnology.City.Name,
                tStateName = tTechnology.City.State.Name,
                tCountryName = tTechnology.City.State.Country.Name,
                tResolutions = (from tR in Context.Resolution
                                 where tR.TechnologyId == tTechnology.TechnologyId
                                 select tR.Measure
                               ),

                tEnableBy = (subCase.Name == null ? null : subCase.Name) + "" + (subCase.FirstLastName == null ? null : subCase.FirstLastName) + " " + (subCase.SecondLastName == null ? null : subCase.SecondLastName),
                                     tEnableDate = tTechnology.EnableDate,
                                     tLastChangeDate = tTechnology.LastChangeDate,
                                     tLastChangeBy = (subCase2.Name == null ? null : subCase2.Name) + " " + (subCase2.FirstLastName == null ? null : subCase2.FirstLastName) + " " + (subCase2.SecondLastName == null ? null : subCase2.SecondLastName),
                                     tDisableDate = tTechnology.DisableDate,
                                     tDisableBy = (subCase3.Name == null ? null : subCase3.Name) + " " + (subCase3.FirstLastName == null ? null : subCase3.FirstLastName) + " " + (subCase3.SecondLastName == null ? null : subCase3.SecondLastName),

            });



            var Technology = (from tTec in Technology1
                              select new
                              {
                                  tTechnologyTechnologyId = Technology1.ToList().Select(t => t.tTechnologyTechnologyId).ToString(),
                                  tTechnologyName = Technology1.ToList().Select(t => t.tTechnologyName).ToString(),
                                  tTechnologyDescription = Technology1.ToList().Select(t => t.tTechnologyDescription).ToString(),
                                  tCityName = Technology1.ToList().Select(t => t.tCityName).ToString(),
                                  tStateName = Technology1.ToList().Select(t => t.tStateName).ToString(),
                                  tCountryName = Technology1.ToList().Select(t => t.tCountryName).ToString(),
                                  tResolutions = String.Join(",", tTec.tResolutions),
                              }
                            );
```

En el segundo query lo que quiero hacer es tomar algunos valores del primero, y ademas, juntar todos las resoluciones que tiene una tecnologia en tResolutios.

al final el segundo query, que se llama Technology, es el que devuelvo.

Gracia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias usar `tTec` para acceder a las propiedades

```
var Technology = (from tTec in Technology1
              select new
              {
                  tTechnologyTechnologyId = tTec.tTechnologyTechnologyId,
                  tTechnologyName = tTec.tTechnologyName,
                  tTechnologyDescription = tTec.tTechnologyDescription,
                  tCityName = tTec.tCityName,
                  tStateName = tTec.tStateName,
                  tCountryName = tTec.tCountryName,
                  tResolutions = String.Join(",", tTec.tResolutions),
              });
```

Al ser la propiedad `Measure` del tipo long deberias convertirla en string en la primer query linq

```
 tResolutions = (from tR in Context.Resolution
                             where tR.TechnologyId == tTechnology.TechnologyId
                             select tR.Measure.ToString()
                           ).ToArray(),
```

Comment: Si, ya he hecho eso, y si tengo tResolutions comentado, entonces todo funciona bien, pero al descomentarlo para usar el String.Join, me tira exception. Ese Join no lo estoy haciendo bien y no se porque. Ya probe poniendo el primer tResolutions un .toList() @Leandro Tuttini

Comment: que exception recibes ? que dice el mensaje. la propiedad Measure de que tipo es ?

Comment: La propiedad Measure es Long, como veras, pues trae una colección de datos, entonces puse un take(1) y me escribe esto System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.CompensatingCollection`1[System.Int64]
Muchas gracias por responderme :d
Aqui esta el codigo en pastebin http://pastebin.com/iEK56EdH
@Leandro Tuttin

Comment: pero el string.Join() solo funciona si la lista es string, si devuelves una lista de long no va a funcionar. Deberias aplicar un ToString() en el primer linq para que esa subquery devuelva una lista de string

Comment: Te refieres a esto?
tResolutions = (from tR in Context.Resolution
                                 where tR.TechnologyId == tTechnology.TechnologyId
                                 select tR.Measure.ToString()
                               ).ToList(),

Comment: muchas gracias por estar contestando

Comment: exacto, edite la respuesta para agregar la modificacion, pero basicamente es lo mismo que has puesto en el comentario

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, no tienes idea de la cantidad de desarrolladores andamos aprendiendo de tus conocimientos! muchas gracias! éxitos y bendiciones :D

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, Asi es, grande tuttini, pero esto me sigue sin funcionar, estoy probando otras cosas como hacer mi primer query un toList()

Comment: pero sigues recibiendo el mensaje de error ? o cambio el problema, en la primer query linq veo que realizas un join, porque no devuelves "collection4"

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por comentario de aliento, me alegra que los aportes sean de utilidad.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ya quite ese join porque estaba haciendo que se repitieran las columnas

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude, todo estaba en que el primer Query tenia que ser una lista

```
 var Technology = Technology1.ToList().AsQueryable().Select( x =>  new 
            {
                tTechnologyTechnologyId = x.tTechnologyTechnologyId,
                tTechnologyName = x.tTechnologyName,
                tTechnologyDescription = x.tTechnologyDescription,
                tCityName = x.tCityName,
                tStateName = x.tStateName,
                tCountryName = x.tCountryName,
                tResolutions = String.Join(",", x.tResolutions),
                tEnableBy = x.tEnableBy,
                tEnableDate = x.tEnableDate,
                tLastChangeDate = x.tLastChangeDate,
                tLastChangeBy = x.tLastChangeBy,
                tDisableDate = x.tDisableDate,
                tDisableBy = x.tDisableBy,
            });
```